# is this possible to assign a value to TimeSpan?

Tags: c#

I have to thank for the early help to advise the "Tick". Now am pretty much got in to my logic except one thing, i have a unix time in my database ,when i was trying to convert to real time and do the logic.

Sorry, let me describe the problem once again,

I have four different timestamp pulled out from DB (Start,End,Start1,End1) converted from unix to real time.  am using the following code to do the conversion

```
DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1970").AddSeconds(SnapTo5Mins(Convert.ToDouble(UnixDate))).AddHours(GMTOFFset);
```

Problem here is,when the value is zero in the coloumn then the date time is returning like (1/1/1970).

for eg. my start value is zero in the database then it retruns (1/1/1970)

1. Step 1: compare the timestamp is not equal to 1/1/1970 (origin time)
   step 2: if its not equal then do Break = End.Subtract(Start); Step
   3: if its equal then assign the break value to zero or whatever step
   4: repeat step 1,2,3 for start1 step 5: concatenate both break +
   break1

   ```
       DateTime Origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0);
       DateTime Start ="01/01/1970 12:00";
       DateTime End = 01/01/1970 12:00";
       DateTime Start1 ="02/10/2013 12:20";
       DateTime End1 = "02/10/2013 02:20";
       TimeSpan Break;,finalMealBreak1;
       if (Origin.Year != Start.Year)
       {
           Break = End.Subtract(Start);
       }
       else
       {
           Break = //Assign constant value zero 
       }
         if (Origin.Year != Start1.Year)
       {
           Break1 = End1.Subtract(Start1);//break1 value must be 2hrs
       }
       else
       {
           Break1 = //Assign constant value zero
       }
      TimeSpan FinalBreakResult = Break + Break1; (FinalBreakresult value suppose to be 2 hrs )
   ```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the question? What is the problem?

Comment: guessing at the problem - Test if `UnixDate` == 0 before doing any conversions. If `UnixDate` is 0 then assign `FinalBreakResult` whatever value you want for this condition.

Comment: I think you just want, `TimeSpan.Zero`, I'll update my answer to use your code in an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to get from the timespan, I think 0? But you can do a few things to get values.

```
TimeSpan.Zero // timespan of 0

DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay // returns a value of the current time in a timespan
                       // obviously also works with any datetime

TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100) // timespan with 100 seconds
                          // There are a few of these, like FromHours, FromDays
```

Edit: Using your code

```
DateTime Origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime Start = DateTime.Parse("01/01/1970 12:00:00");
DateTime End = DateTime.Parse("01/01/1970 12:00:00");
DateTime Start1 = DateTime.Parse("02/10/2013 12:20:00");
DateTime End1 = DateTime.Parse("02/10/2013 14:20:00");
TimeSpan Break, Break1;

if (Origin.Year != Start.Year)
{
    Break = End.Subtract(Start);
}
else
{
    Break = TimeSpan.Zero;
}
if (Origin.Year != Start1.Year)
{
    Break1 = End1.Subtract(Start1);//break1 value must be 2hrs
}
else
{
    Break1 = TimeSpan.Zero;
}

TimeSpan FinalBreakResult = Break + Break1;
// Value of FinalBreakResult is 2 hours
```

Comment: Note: I did update End1 to be 14:20 instead of 02:20, I assume you meant 2pm? :>

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck on that point.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. To add to @Dan Saltmer's answer:

```
DateTime then = DateTime.Now;
Thread.Sleep(500);
TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - then;
```